# How to return a IObservable<T> in aws lambda

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, system.reactive

I'm looking to return an `IEnumerable<T>` that is streamed on the response body for the consumer of a AWS lambda function in a push based notification.

```
Consumer|---Call---------Object1------Object2----Object3----Finish
              v           ^            ^         ^          ^
Lambda  |---Start-----Object1-----Object2------Object3-----End
```

So that the consumer of this lambda function can read the response body as a stream, in an anecdote if we had lambda responding [1,2,3] with one second wait between each item, then consumer would receive [1, {1 second} 2, {1 second} 3].
Any lead on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var values = new [] { 1, 2, 3, };

var observable =
    Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Zip(values, (_, v) => v);
```

Comment: Does simply responding iobervable in lambda ensure clients consuming the lambda an async response? What about serialization, won't it consume the entire response before returning?

Comment: @JohniMichels - You really need to explain those two questions to me a lot more clearly. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, if I request a POST on the endpoint of an aws lambda that is returning iobservable, what will ensure that the response is pushed item by item? Asking because even a serializer on lambda side that consumes the entire object before returning its string equivalent will make client wait 2 seconds and return [1, 2, 3].

Comment: @JohniMichels - Yes, I'm not 100% following what you're saying. The observable will push the static list out on a new thread and it will push them item by item.

Comment: Yes, when you're talking thread on the same machine that is consuming the assembly that returns the iobservable. What I'm asking is for a client over internet that calls an aws lambda function that returns a list in a push like fashion.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I really don't understand what you're asking. Can you ask someone to help phrase what you're asking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190121/discussion-between-johni-michels-and-enigmativity).